How to stop Chrome from ever breaking on debugger command?
At my work there's a component with an explicit "debugger" command that interrupts me every time I run the application with dev tools open. I do not have access to the source code of this component. How can I stop Chrome from EVER breaking on ANY "debugger" command? I tried going to sources and disabling breakpoints (Ctrl + F8) but that only remains as long as the browser is open.
